# ggplot2 is not printing all the information I need in R

Tags: json, r, ggplot2

I am trying to replicate the following script:  [San Francisco Crime  Classification](https://www.kaggle.com/benhamner/sf-crime/san-francisco-top-crimes-map/code)

here is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(rjson)
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
library(jsonlite)



train=jsonlite::fromJSON("/home/felipe/Templates/Archivo de prueba/databritanica.json")

counts <- summarise(group_by(train, Crime_type), Counts=length(Crime_type))
#counts <- counts[order(-counts$Crime_type),]
# This removes the "Other Offenses" category
top12 <- train[train$Crime_type %in% counts$Crime_type[c(1,3:13)],]


map<-get_map(location=c(lon = -2.747770, lat = 53.389499)  ,zoom=12,source="osm")

p <- ggmap(map) +
  geom_point(data=top12, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, color=factor(Crime_type)), alpha=0.05) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1.0, size=6.0),
                               title="Type of Crime")) +
  scale_colour_brewer(type="qual",palette="Paired") + 
  ggtitle("Top Crimes in Britain") +
  theme_light(base_size=20) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
ggsave("united kingdom_top_crimes_map.png", p, width=14, height=10, units="in")
```

I am reading the data from a JSON file and try to print points over the map according to the data.   Each point is a type of crime that is have been committed, the location of each point depends of two parameters: longitude and latitude.

What is the problem?  the points are not being printing.   The script generate a new map without the points that is suppose to show.

This is the original map:  [image: http://i.imgur.com/agSZ3sP.png]

And  this is the result: [image]

Any ideas??

This a example of the data contain in the JSON file is:

```
[
{"Month":"2014-05","Longitude":-2.747770,"Latitude":53.389499,"Location":"On or near Cronton Road","LSOA_name":"Halton 001B","Crime_type":"Other theft"},

{"Month":"2014-05","Longitude":-2.799099,"Latitude":53.354676,"Location":"On or near Old Higher Road","LSOA_name":"Halton 008B","Crime_type":"Anti-social behaviour"},

{"Month":"2014-05","Longitude":-2.804451,"Latitude":53.352456,"Location":"On or near Higher Road","LSOA_name":"Halton 008B","Crime_type":"Anti-social behaviour"}

]
```

Comment: Have you tested with a higher value for alpha?  An alpha of .05 makes points that are nearly transparent, which I can barely see even without a background map.

Comment: You also need to calm down a bit with all the `library()` calls. It looks like the only packages you need to explicitly call are `ggplot2`, `ggmap`, `dplyr`, and `jsonlite`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Your `alpha = 0.05` is making the points practically invisible when plotted on the colorful map background, as mentioned by @aosmith.

Longer answer:

I suggest the following changes to your `geom_point`:

- Increase the `alpha` to something more reasonable
- Increase the `size` of the points
- Optionally, change the `shape` to one with a background and fill for better visibility

  - This will require you to change the `fill` parameter in `aes`, as well as the `scale_color_brewer` to `scale_fill_brewer`

Example:

```
# Load required packages
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(jsonlite)

# Example data provided in question, with one manually entered entry with
# Crime_type = "Other Offenses"
'[
{"Month":"2014-05","Longitude":-2.747770,"Latitude":53.389499,"Location":"On or near Cronton Road","LSOA_name":"Halton 001B","Crime_type":"Other theft"},
{"Month":"2014-05","Longitude":-2.799099,"Latitude":53.354676,"Location":"On or near Old Higher Road","LSOA_name":"Halton 008B","Crime_type":"Anti-social behaviour"},
{"Month":"2014-05","Longitude":-2.804451,"Latitude":53.352456,"Location":"On or near Higher Road","LSOA_name":"Halton 008B","Crime_type":"Anti-social behaviour"},
{"Month":"2014-05","Longitude":-2.81,"Latitude":53.36,"Location":"On or near Higher Road","LSOA_name":"Halton 008B","Crime_type":"Other Offenses"}

]' -> example_json
train <- fromJSON(example_json)

# Process the data, the dplyr way
counts <- train %>% 
  group_by(Crime_type) %>% 
  summarise(Counts = length(Crime_type))

# This removes the "Other Offenses" category
top12 <- train %>% 
  filter(Crime_type != "Other Offenses")

# Get the map
map <- get_map(location=c(lon = -2.747770, lat = 53.389499), zoom=12, source="osm")

# Plotting code
p <- ggmap(map) +
  # Changes made to geom_point. 
  # I increased the alpha and size, and I used a shape that has 
  # a black border and a fill determined by Crime_type.
  geom_point(data=top12, aes(x=Longitude, y=Latitude, fill=factor(Crime_type)),
             shape = 21, alpha = 0.75, size = 3.5, color = "black") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha=1.0, size=6.0),
                               title="Type of Crime")) +
  # Changed scale_color_brewer to scale_fill_brewer
  scale_fill_brewer(type="qual", palette="Paired") + 
  ggtitle("Top Crimes in Britain") +
  theme_light(base_size=20) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank())
```

[image: Better map]

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer.  It works perfectly,  I upvote and accepted your answer.   Thank you